# Multiple Select & INNER JOIN Multiple Where clause

Tags: php, mysql, join, inner-join

I have 4 tables 
`we_vehicles_coordinates`
`we_vehicles`
`we_drivers`
`we_clients`

```
SELECT mrk_lat,we_clients.client_id,mrk_lng ,engine_status ,created_date,live_fuel,
                    count(we_drivers.driver_id) as total_drivers,
                    count(we_vehicles.veh_id) as total_veh,
                    count(we_vehicles.veh_status) as run_veh,
                    count(we_vehicles.veh_status) as stop_veh
                    FROM `we_vehicles_coordinates` 
                INNER JOIN we_vehicles ON
                    we_vehicles.veh_id = we_vehicles_coordinates.veh_id
                INNER JOIN we_drivers ON
                    we_drivers.veh_id = we_vehicles.veh_id
                INNER JOIN we_clients ON 
                    we_clients.client_id = we_vehicles.client_id
                    WHERE (we_vehicles.veh_status='1') AND
                    (we_vehicles.veh_status='0') AND
                    (we_clients.client_id= 3)
```

It gives me `null` and `0`.
Tried a lot but didn't got success.
Thanks

Comment: `issue 1. aggregate function without group by`  `issue 2. perhaps no matching record with inner join`. So better provide some sample data and expected result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`we_vehicles.veh_status` cannot equal 1 and 0 simultaneously.

or as it was put by a comment below:

```
SELECT /* stuff here */
   , SUM(IF(we_vehicles.veh_status = 1, 1, 0) AS run_veh
   , SUM(IF(we_vehicles.veh_status = 0, 1, 0) AS stop_veh
FROM /* more stuff */
WHERE (we_vehicles.veh_status in ('1','0') AND (we_clients.client_id= 3)
;
```

Note: I am not sure the JOINs you are using are necessarily appropriate for the final result you want, and using a `GROUP BY` might be appropriate as well.

Comment: so what will be the solution if i want the count of 0 and 1's from the same `we_vehicles.veh_status` ?

Comment: @uueerdo unless you believe this proof... http://www.pleacher.com/mp/mhumor/onezero2.html

Comment: @shafee `WHERE we_vehicles.veh_status in ('1','0') AND
                    we_clients.client_id= 3`  OR... `WHERE ((we_vehicles.veh_status='1') OR
                    (we_vehicles.veh_status='0')) AND
                    (we_clients.client_id= 3)`

Comment: @xQbert i want both 0 and 1 with separate  `as clause`, How that can be done.

Comment: @Shafee I am not positive what you mean, but see the edit above ...in a moment.

Answer (score 0):

According to your table and something you want, I suggest instead of using `join` use `union` (and If you want to duplicate rows, use `union all`)